# Trying to append col.name on to a vector

Tags: function, r

I have several functions that I am trying to implement in R(studio).  I will show the simplest one. I am trying to append names on to a vector for later use as a col.name.

```
# Initialize
headerA <- vector(mode="character",length=20)
headerA[1]="source";headerA[2]="matches"

# Function - add on new name
h <- function(df, compareA, compareB) {
   new_header <- paste(compareA,"Vs",compareB,sep="_")
   data.frame(df,new_header)
}
# Comparison 1:
compareA <-"AA"
compareB <-"BB"
headers <- (headerA, compareA, compareB)
```

But I am getting this error and it is very puzzling.  I have googled it but the search is too vague/broad.
When run I get:

> headers <- (headerA, compareA, compareB)
>   Error: unexpected ',' in "headers <- (headerA,"

The second error for the other function is similar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a call to your function `h` and just have an open `(` instead:

```
headers <- h(headerA, compareA, compareB)
```

Results in:

```
        df new_header
1   source   AA_Vs_BB
2  matches   AA_Vs_BB
3            AA_Vs_BB
4            AA_Vs_BB
...
```

Comment: @oax - happens to the best of us :). Good luck.